# Generic type casting vs parameterized type casting in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

I know the general differences between generic types and parameterized types, and I know some general rules:

- List<A> and List<B> have no inheritance relationship, even if A and B are related through an inheritance chain;
- Object[] cannot be cast to String[], unless the Object[] array was constructed using new String[n].

But my question is a bit specific. So I am going to give some code.

According to the above general rules, the cast in the following 2 examples is invalid:

```
static List<String> f1a(List<String> list) {
    return List.of((String[]) list.toArray());  // ClassCastException
}

static List<String> f2a(List<String> list) {
    return (List<String>) List.of(list.toArray());  // compile-time error: Inconvertible types
}
```

Now if I replace the String type with a generic type parameter E, the casting works! But I really don't understand why?

```
// f1 is a generic version f1a, where String -> E
static <E> List<E> f1(List<E> list) {
    return List.of((E[]) list.toArray());
}

// f2 is a generic version f2a, where String -> E
static <E> List<E> f2(List<E> list) {
    return (List<E>) List.of(list.toArray());
}
```

The following demo shows that f1 and f2 are valid, while f1a and f2a are problematic:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = List.of("hello", "world");

    List<String> copy1 = f1(list);  // works
    System.out.println(copy1);

    List<String> copy2 = f2(list);  // works
    System.out.println(copy2);

    List<String> copy1a = f1a(list);  // ClassCastException
    System.out.println(copy1a);

    List<String> copy2a = f2a(list);  // compile-time error
    System.out.println(copy2a);
}
```

Comment: Those are *unsafe casts.*  If you enable all compiler warnings, the compiler will tell you that they’re unsafe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f1` works because of type erasure. The cast to `E[]` is completely removed at runtime, meaning that your code would behave something like this at runtime, but it does let the compiler infer that you're returning a `List<E>` and not a `List<Object>`, therefore letting the program compile.

```
static List f1(List list) {
  return List.of(list.toArray());
}
```

---

`f2` works because of basically the same reason. This time, the result of `List.of(list.toArray())` is inferred to be a `List<Object>` because `toArray` returns an `Object[]`, but the cast, which is later erased, makes it compile.

---

`f1a` has a `ClassCastException` because you're trying to turn an `Object[]` into a `String[]`. In Java, arrays know the type they were declared with even at runtime, so the array returned by `toArray` thinks of itself as an `Object[]` even though it really only holds strings and doesn't like being turned into a `String[]`.

`f2a` doesn't work because you can't turn a `List<Object>` into a `List<String>`.

If you want to turn your list into an array of strings, try `list.toArray(new String[0])`. This way, it will return a proper `String[]` and not cause problems.

If you convert a `List<Object>` to a `List<String>`, cast to a raw type with `(List) List.of(list.toArray())`

Comment: If f1 or f2 returns a List<Object>, how can I assign it to List<String>: List<String> copy1 = f1(list);

Comment: @Peng Cast to the raw type `List`. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, I think I almost got it. But just to double check my understanding: List<String> copy1 = f1(list) is erased to List copy1 = f1(list), where List<String> is erased to raw List, and the return type of f1(), which was declared List<E>, is also erased to raw type List. So compiler accepts the assignment to be valid (a raw List is assigned to a raw List). At runtime, the List behaves as List<String> because the elements are Strings ("hello", "world"). Am I right?

Comment: @Peng Yup, pretty much. Raw types are for backward compatibility. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Comment: Thanks. I do find type erasure very confusing sometimes. Most of the time, we can ignore it as a user of generics; but in some special cases (especially when we are writing a generic method), we must take it into account. My above question originates  from the Java Collections Framework source code for List.copyOf(), Set.copyOf(), Map.copyOf(), all of which use a toArray() without any argument (thus returning an Object[] array), and then a final cast to List<E> is required (which is erased to a raw List; the tricky part).

Answer (score 1):

`f1a` case:

Here, the explicit casting is done, which means that compiler expects the same type at the compile time. By providing explicit cast `(String[]) list.toArray()`, you tell to your compiler, that whatever is returned by `.toArray()`, it should attempt to cast it to `String[]`, and hence you want to build a `List.of(String[])`, which also constitutes a return type of your method. This is why it doesn't have any compile-time problem, but rather it throws run-time exception, as it can't cast `Object` to `String`. Think of it as at the compile time, explicitly given instruction is correct for the compiler, but it doesn't work at run-time. To understand more about casting, please also see [Checked Casts at Runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.3) and maybe also [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6).

`f2a`case:

`.toArray()` method of `ArrayList`, [by method definition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()) returns `Object[]`. That's why you get the list of objects, which can't be downcasted to list of Strings, and this happens, because it can't cast it and this is a [checked cast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.2), and you get compile-time Exception, i.e. your code doesn't compile.